# Defining a new Win+key shortcut

Tags: windows-xp, keyboard-shortcuts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create a new keyboard shortcut using the Windows key on WinXP](https://superuser.com/questions/112981/how-to-create-a-new-keyboard-shortcut-using-the-windows-key-on-winxp)

Is it possible to define new WinKey+some_key shortcuts? How would one go about it?

Also, is it possible to somehow redefine Win-E (starts Windows Explorer)  shortcut in the registry?

Comment: Why? Is it really that useful to you? Sorry for the downvote.

Comment: @OlofEdler - Which part? About the general mapping, yes (I have tons of other shortcuts already mapped to alt and control keys, from volume control, to notes programs, to shortcuts to my most used quick applications ... <- travel often, rarely use mouse). About the Win+E, yes, I switched to a different file manager a while ago.

Comment: In any case I didn't understand the reason for the downvote, but if you feel that way, then, by all means ...

Answer (score 5):

One of the easiest, and my favorite, ways to use keyboard shortcuts is with [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) (AHK). Defining a new <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Key</kbd> shortcut can be as simple as:

```
#x::

;do something

Exit
```

The [documentation](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/) is a great start and provides many examples. If you need more help, the [community forum](http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/) is another great resource.

Comment: Autohotkey is always the answer!

Comment: @surfasb As evident from many of my answers here on SU. :P