# Assigning either Windows Key a new function (with or without autohotkey)

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey, windows-key

So, simply said, I want to use the right Windows Key as a push-to-talk button.
There's a small twist to it: I'm using a StinkyBoard as my talking button, so I have my hands free to type or play a game or whatever, even while I'm talking.
The StinkyBoard can only be assigned keyboard keys, so right now, using any keyboard key to talk with interferes either when I'm typing, or when I'm playing games. So I need a unique key, that has a function all to its own, one not commonly used anywhere. The Windows Keys, or the context menu key (also called "Apps") would do nicely.
How do I map either of those keys in such a way, that they do not use the standard OS given function, but rather only return whether or not they're being pushed? StinkyBoard drivers recognize both keys without trouble, but so long as they actually do the whole context menu or windows start menu thing, I can't use them for push-to-talk.

Thanks,
PaterFrog

Comment: Why don't you use something like **`** which almost never has an in-game mapping ( or if it does it can be changed ).  Have you tried autohotkey to see if it can be done.  Its very likely the application watch for that key anyways.

Comment: Because it still has a function when typing stuff.
I need to be able to press a keyboard key ANYTIME without ever having to worry about it interefering with anything I'm doing. Not by zooming in or out web pages, not by typing or deleting anything, not by opening or pausing anything. It should only register is an existing keyboard button, whereby F13 and higher don't work.

Comment: What program are you using for talk? That program also needs to be instructed to see the shortkey as a push-to-talk button. And what is the key now for push-to-talk on the keyboard?

Comment: Not any one single program, this button would be used with Mumble, Ventrilo, TS and such. Most even just halfway serious programs recognize F13 and higher, but the problem here is, is that I'm using a StinkyBoard, basically buttons for your feet. The drivers of that thing don't recognize anything not on modern keyboards, which includes mouse buttons and keys such as F13.
To fix that, I need to learn how to assign the winkeys, or the menu or the CAPS lock keys a new function in the sense that they are still those keys, but don't open any menus, or do anything to disrupt any programs anymore.

Comment: Currently I'm using Rctrl, which messes with browsers by zooming, games by actions such as crouching, tertiary action bars, lockin onto targets you might not want to lock, etc. If it was for example possible to tell the right windows key that it is still the right windows key, but should under no circumstance even attempt to open the start menu, I'd be perfectly happy. I can't be losing focus even for a moment, which I think happens if you only tell the key to open and then shut the menu in one quick action. Instead, the action should not be taken at all.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you want and if it works with your setup but you could make a AutoHotkey file with `AppsKey::!^,`. This would remap your Content-menu-key to `Ctrl+Alt+,` which you could use in the other programs to do the function. (You could still use Alt+Space for the content-menu but your real key would generate `Ctrl+Alt+,`.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What does Ctrl+Alt+ usually do? I just tried it but nothing seemed to happen.

Comment: It does nothing. At least in the programs i know. You could use any key-stoke you know isn't used. So you could use that key-stroke to assign in other programs (Which can't map the Content-Key but can map some other key) to do a function. I tried it with GreenShot (My screenshot program of choice for SU:) and although GS can map the Content-key itself i remapped the Content-key with AutoHk to `Ctrl+Alt+,` and set GS to take an image on `Ctrl+Alt+,` and it worked. BTW if i use the Content-key direct in GS and use it the content-menu does not show so i'm not sure why that doesn't work for you.

Comment: Sadly the driver of the StinkyBoard doesn't accept Ctrl+Alt+. :(

Comment: What key-combination can you assign in StinkyBoard? You need to find one you know is almost never used and use that.

Comment: I had to use the German letters ö, ä, ü and also ´. Which still doesn't change the fact, that these letters interfere with typing. Atleast most games don't do anything with them.
I've received an answer from the StinkyBoard support, telling me that they'll release an upgraded version of their driver Q1 2014. Let's hope that does it. :D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a new keyboard shortcut using the Windows key on WinXP](http://superuser.com/questions/112981/how-to-create-a-new-keyboard-shortcut-using-the-windows-key-on-winxp)